# Shrink whitespace in gg_vistime plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, vistime

I am looking to shrink the white space around my timeline in the gg_vistime function. Here is the code to produce my plot. Plot is attached.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggvis)
library(vistime)
library(ggpubr)


data <- read.csv(text="timeframe,group,start,end,color,
                       pre,october,2019-09-25,2019-10-10,#3399FF,
                       5,october,2019-10-10,2019-10-15,#FFECB3,
                       10,october,2019-10-15,2019-10-20,#FFD54F,
                       15,october,2019-10-20,2019-10-25,#FFB300")

date_vector <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-09-25", "2019-10-10","2019-10-15", "2019-10-20","2019-10-25"))

report_timelines <- gg_vistime(data, col.event = "timeframe", col.start = "start", col.end = "end",optimize_y = TRUE, linewidth = 10, show_labels = FALSE, title = "Timeline of Reports")
report_timelines <- report_timelines +
  ggplot2::theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size=14),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, color = "black", angle = 30, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
    axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
    scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_vector, date_labels = "%b %d \n%Y")
    
report_timelines
dummy <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x = start, y = group, fill = color)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#3399FF","#FFECB3","#FFD54F","#FFB300"),
                    labels = c("15 days before", "5 days after", "10 days after", "15 days after")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title= "Timeframe"))
dummy

leg <- get_legend(dummy)
all <- ggarrange(report_timelines, legend.grob = leg, legend  = "right")
all
```

[image: timeline]

Comment: You can resize your plot window so it's not so tall. Plots are designed to take up as much space as you give them. Are you suing `ggsave` or something to create the image file?